# How to extract a single file from a large ZIP archive

Tags: node.js, unzip

How to extract one file from zipped directory?
Zlib doesn't have any file browsing features, neither does extract-zip
So I don't know what to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`EvanOxfeld/node-unzip`](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip#parse-zip-file-contents) parse zip file contents:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var unzip = require('unzip')
var path = require('path')
var mkdir = require('mkdirp')

fs.createReadStream('./archive.zip')
  .pipe(unzip.Parse())
  .on('entry', function (entry) {

    var fileName = entry.path
    var type = entry.type

    if (type==='File' && fileName === 'dir/fileInsideDir.txt') {

      var fullPath = __dirname + '/output/' + path.dirname( fileName )
      fileName = path.basename( fileName )
      mkdir.sync(fullPath)
      entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream( fullPath + '/' + fileName ))

    } else {
      entry.autodrain()
    }

  })
```

[ [Example archive](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip/raw/master/testData/compressed-OSX-Finder/archive.zip) ]